# how to write a file to a remote server using rhdfs, R and hadoop dfs

Tags: r, hadoop, hdfs

I have a R script in which I have a data frame and I want to write this data frame to the remote server. I found this command which write a data frame to a file:

`write.table (data_frame, file=pipe ("hadoop dfs -put - /path/to/file.txt"), sep="\t")`

But the problem with this command is that it writes to the local system instead of remote server. How can I modify the command so that it writes to remote server. My major objective is to be able to write the data frame (without col name and row name) in R script to a  file on remote server. If there is some better way then please suggest me.

Comment: So, what would you write at a system prompt?

Comment: @BondedDust basically I want to run the R script which is present on one server but want to write the data frame to remote hdfs. with above command I am only able to write to local hdfs. Sorry I couldn't get what you meant by system prompt.

Comment: Presumably you have some method of interacting with your unnamed OS. That is what I was calling a "system prompt".

Comment: @BondedDust I have CentOS on my local machine and also on remote machine. I am calling  a Java class on my local machine which in turn calls the R script present on the same local machine. The data frame in R script is what I want to write on remote machine from within the R script. Once R script execution is successfully over it returns success message to Java class

Comment: @BondedDust I do not understand how this question is a possible duplicate? The post mentioned is related to use terminal to execute remote R script whereas my post is related to writing to remote hdfs using `write.table` within a R script

Comment: It seemed that you were missing the knowledge to ssh into the remote machine and use the OS file transfer facilities with `system()`.